Validation error for AzureOpenAIEmbeddings
When running my program,

pydantic.v1.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for
AzureOpenAIEmbeddings
root

As of openai>=1.0.0, Azure endpoints should be specified via the azure_endpoint param not openai_api_base (or alias base_url).  (type=value_error)
This error message shows up and I am unable to run.
openai version: 1.30.1
Referring to the below code, I am already using AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINTand not openai_api_base.
from langchain_openai import AzureOpenAIEmbeddings, OpenAIEmbeddings
embeddings = AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(
azure_endpoint=os.environ["AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT"],
...
]


I resolved the azure_endpoint issue by addressing conflicts in environment variables. After upgrading all packages to the latest versions (openai==1.52.2, langchain==0.3.4, and langchain-openai==0.2.3), I checked if the "OPENAI_API_BASE" environment variable was present and removed it if necessary:
import os

# Check and remove conflicting environment variable
if "OPENAI_API_BASE" in os.environ:
    del os.environ["OPENAI_API_BASE"]

After this, I was able to successfully run:
azure_embeddings = AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(
    openai_api_version=azure_configs["openai_api_version"],
    azure_endpoint=azure_configs["azure_endpoint"],
    azure_deployment=azure_configs["embedding_deployment"],
    model=azure_configs["embedding_name"],
)

